# Obtaining Non-Summary Zonal Statistics from Raster Data

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1. The data I am looking for are zonal statistics from a raster using polygon-defined zones. I can use the Zonal tools to calculate *summary statistics*, but I am looking for the entire range of values. Surely, if it can calculate the summary stats, it must be able to create an output of some format with the entire range of individual values. Any ideas? (FYI: I am unacquainted with writing code for ArcGIS)

Comment: There's Range value option in statistics tool. Are you talking about something else?

Comment: What about Zonal Statistics as Table with a statistics type of ALL then join by attributes to your input polygon.. short of that iterate your geometries, extract by mask to a temp raster object then read the raster as numpy array https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000 and iterate over the values for each polygon to make your own statistical type. PS when using Zonal Statistics as Table I would recommend geodatabase features, not a shapefile, otherwise *any* edit will reorder the FID and destroy the relationship between the table and the polygons.

Comment: @FelixIP  Yes, I'm not looking for the range (max minus min), but rather the entire set of values from which all of those summary stats are calculated. Basically, the non-summarized data.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I'll look into that. And thanks for the heads-up about the gdb vs. shp issue.

Comment: I'll add a little info about what I'm trying to do. I'm an archaeologist looking at ice patches in the high country. I have identified the ice patches on aerial imagery and trace polygon features over them. I also have rasters for elevation, slope, and aspect from which I am attempting to obtain data overlain by the polygons. I would like the entire dataset of non-summarized data for the individual polygons in each raster. I am attempting to look for a left or right skew or bimodality in the frequencies of values within each polygon. The summary stats are not great for this.

Comment: I'm trying to get an idea of the geomorphic constraints that predict the presence of ice patches.

Comment: Convert to points, use near to compute polygon.

Comment: Wind drifts and surrounding topography defines their presence, unless patches are remains of avalanches.

Comment: Here was my workaround:
1) Clip raster using polygon features
2) Reclassify using defined interval of 1
3) Convert raster to polygons
4) Add Surface Information (z min, z max, z mean)
5) Copy all records and paste into Excel

Comment: I don’t know why ESRI makes that so difficult. All the data I want are contained in cells within the raster. Why ESRI hasn’t created an obvious way to compile the value for each cell into a table or export the data to a txt or xls is a mystery. Maybe I’m missing something with how raster data are encoded. I don’t know. The software can compute summary stats and histograms from the raster cell values, but you can’t extract the data and perform those summaries yourself.